# Concerning the usage of "something and something of something"

Tags: conjunctions, phrase-usage

I'm very confused about a specific usage of the "and" (I think). Here is the case:

> This fascinating distance and loss of singularity

What this phrase means? Are "fascinating distance" and "loss" belong to "singularity"? Or, are they basically two different things?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the complete sentence, because it doesn't seem very meaningful to me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, my question isn't phrase-specific. Let me try this one:

"The shiny light and cloudlessness of sky are beatiful." In this case, "shiny light" and "cloudlessness" are belong to the sky? Can I write this phrase like this: "The shiny light, and cloudlessness of sky", or this two phrase mean two different things?

Comment: Are you simply asking whether adjectival ***fascinating*** in your example applies to ***loss*** as well as to ***distance**?* And/or whether ***of distance*** applies to ***the [fascinating] distance*** as well as to ***loss**?* If that's the question, the answer is that ***syntactically, the text is ambiguous***. You have to use common sense to decide what was meant. But these are questions better addressed on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, constructions like this can be ambiguous. Often context or common sense come to the rescue, but recasting sentences can help reduce ambiguity. If I say "I hate people and traffic in the city," then perhaps I'm a misanthrope who hates all people in general, and also by the way don't care much for city traffic. *Or* people and traffic, together, are what I hate about the city. Context and common sense suggest the latter. I could also simply recast the sentence to be less ambiguous: "I hate the city's people and traffic." Or even "I hate *the* people and traffic in the city," in which the definite article helps make my scope clear.

Using your second example, "the shiny light and cloudlessness of sky are beautiful," if you want to make it clear that "light" is a property of "sky" you could simply reword it: "The sky's shiny light and cloudlessness." Or, for the opposite meaning, "The shiny light and cloudless sky are" (which is perhaps the most comfortable construction). In your first example, "this fascinating distance and loss of singularity" is hard to misunderstand because "distance of singularity" doesn't really make sense (for that matter... I'm not too sure, without context, what "loss of singularity" really means either).